# Почему проект Asp.net Core запускается из Visual Studio, а из exe файла -ошибки?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

С чем может быть связаны ошибки проекта, если запускаю exe файл?В то же время-этот же проект из Visual Studio- работает. Странно. Включил логи-Во время запуска приложения без студии пишет ,что не может найти представление. А вот со студией- находит....какой-то бред.
Подскажите, в чём может быть дело?
Вот скриншот
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скриншоты выкладывайте не ссылками, а прямо в вопрос загружайте.

Comment: А лучше исключение в текстовом виде.

Comment: Интересно какой exe вы запускаете, ежели asp.net core компилируется в dll? Там же надо запускать через команду `dotnet run`.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Пути неверные были. Студия берёт папку Views,статические файлы с главного каталога, а проект компилируется в другую папку, а там соответственно этих файлов нет. Либо надо прописать для этого точный путь к файлам.

Comment: @Bulson , а кстати, если пути прописываю-не работает. Приходится копировать папки с представлениями и стат файлами в папку с exe. А как прописать, что б путь брался с главной директории приложения? Я писал абсолютный путь и со знаком ~ , но всё-равно не находится файл

Comment: А пробовали делать Publish/File? Студия сама скомпилит самодостаточное приложение и его можно будет запустить.